# Пользовательский тип данных

Tags: c#

У меня есть задание, в котором говорится о том, что необходимо разработать собственный тип данных, похожий на `int`. Ему необходимо реализовать ряд методов, например `add` и т.п. У этого типа размерность чисел должна **ограничиваться лишь доступной памятью**, т.е. он будет больше `long`.

Я залез в метаданных типа `int` и обнаружил, что тип реализован как структура данных, также в файле имеется указание на максимальное и минимальное допустимое значение значение. Методы с которыми умеет работать данных тип только инициализированны, например `public static Int32 Parse(string s);`.

На основе вышесказанного возникает вопрос - **как реализовывать пользовательский тип данных в C#?**

Я предположил, что хочу добиться чего-то похожего на это:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyInt a = 5;
    MyInt b = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(a.Add(b));
}
```

Для этого руководствуясь логикой я написал следующее:

```
public readonly struct MyInt
{
    public const MyInt MaxValue = 2147483647;
    public const MyInt MinValue = -2147483648;

    public static MyInt Add(MyInt b)
    {
        MyInt c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

Однако обнаружил, что весь этот код превратился в одну большую ошибку. Собственно подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить или где почитать об этом.

Comment: потому что `readonly` в определении структуры лишнее, плюс не переопределен оператор `+` для `MyInt`, плюс, внутри `Add` откуда-то берется переменная `a`

Comment: Основывался на коде указанном в int32. Там есть и readonly, + там нет. Да в методе add я понимаю, что нет переменной а, но как её туда передать из указанной мной записи я не понимаю. Поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Где ты смотришь код `int32`?

Comment: кроме того для встроенных числовых типов операторы добавляются самой clr. Для своих - нужно самому вручную добавлять операторы.

Comment: System.Int32, я бы назвал это заголовочным файлом или что-то вроде того.

Comment: Как ты в него попадаешь?

Comment: Если объявить переменную, например int f;, при наведении на int, вылазит меню и в нем написано readonly struct System.Int32

Comment: ага, у меня без readonly в этом случае показывает, в любом случае, операторы в этот тип добавляются не в коде

Answer (score 4):

То, что вас попросили сделать — написать собственную реализацию типа [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1).

Это как раз целочисленный тип, способный хранить числа произвольной длины. Хранится он в виде массива байт или массива целых или массива длинных целых.

Если речь идёт о байтах, то число представляется в 256-ричной системе счисления, где каждый байт это одна цифра. Например, массив из *n* байтов *d*<sub>0</sub>...*d*<sub>n - 1</sub> означает число

256<sup>n - 1</sup>×*d*<sub>0</sub>+256<sup>n - 2</sup>×*d*<sub>1</sub>+...+256<sup>1</sup>×*d*<sub>n - 2</sub>+256<sup>0</sup>×*d*<sub>n - 1</sub>

Это похоже на то, как представлены числа в десятичной системе:

31415 = 10<sup>4</sup>×3+10<sup>3</sup>×1+10<sup>2</sup>×4+10<sup>1</sup>×1+10<sup>0</sup>×5

Знак можно хранить отдельно от числа, либо в старшем бите числа, в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Можно реализовать метод `Negate`, который будет *обращать* число, скажем, превращать 5 в -5 и наоборот.

Сложение двух чисел одинаковой размерности выполняется также, как и сложение в столбик. Нам точно также приходится учитывать флаг переноса, если сумма двух байтов больше, чем 255.

```cs
public byte[] Add(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    Debug.Assert(a.Length == b.Length);

    List<byte> c = new List<byte>(a.Length);
    int curry = 0;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int sum = a[i] + b[i] + curry;
        if (sum > 255)
        {
            c.Add(sum - 255);
            curry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            c.Add(sum);
            curry = 0;
        }
    }

    if (curry == 1)
        c.Insert(0, 0xFF);
    else if (c[0] > 127)
        c.Insert(0, 0x00);

    return c.ToArray();
}
```

Здесь переменная `curry` хранит флаг переноса, и может принимать значения 0 или 1. Сравните алгоритм со сложением десятичных чисел в столбик, вручную сложив 12345 и 23456.

Вот эти строки нужны, чтобы обработать старший бит числа, если вы храните числа в дополнительном коде:

```cs
    if (curry == 1)
        c.Insert(0, 0xFF);
    else if (c[0] > 127)
        c.Insert(0, 0x00);
```

Для сложения двух числе разной размерности, нужно дополнить меньшее число байтами вначале до нужного размера. Если число было отрицательным (старший бит нулевого байта установлен), добавлять надо байты 0xFF, а если положительным — байты 0x00.

Вычитание — это сложение `Add` с дополнением `Negate`.

Про алгоритмы умножения и деления можно прочитать в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Я бы рекомендовал разобраться с алгоритмами и попытаться реализовать их самостоятельно. Впрочем, .NET сейчас поставляется с открытым исходным кодом, поэтому можете взглянуть на [реализацию `BigInteger`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить что-то похожее на это:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyInt a = 5;
    MyInt b = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(a.Add(b));
}
```

необходимо описать что-то похожее на это:

```
public struct MyInt {
  private byte[] m;
  public MyInt Add (MyInt b) { /* смотри ответ Mark Shevchenko*/ }
  // Также нужно определить неявные преобразования
  // типа int в MyInt
  public static implicit operator MyInt(int x) {
    // Здесь из int нужно получить MyInt
    // и вернуть как результат
  }
}
```

Для большей красоты погугли тему "Перегрузка операторов" и сделай возможность сложения через оператор "+":

```
MyInt a = 5;
MyInt b = 10;
MyInt c = a + b;
```